# How to find anchor tag in div and add class?

Tags: jquery

I have a particular div class in which there is anchor tag with no class and i have to add class to it using jquery.
This is sample html

```
<div id="mydiv"><a href="www.google.com">myclass</a></div>
```

This is what i am trying but not working

```
$('.myclass','a').attr('class','myclass');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('.myclass a').attr('class','myclass');` - use descendant or child selector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `.addClass()`:

```
$('#mydiv a').addClass('myclass');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9WAk/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$('#mydiv a').addClass('myclass');
```

### OR

```
$('#mydiv').find('a').addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 2):

`mydiv` is an id. Id is referred as `#id` in jQuery.

`find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of the elements in the DOM tree.

`addClass()` adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.

```
$("#mydiv").find("a").addClass("myclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#mydiv > a').addClass('myclass');
```

- This will find any child anchor inside the div with id `mydiv`
- Then you can simply add a class to it using the jQuery [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method.

In case, the anchor is not a direct child of `mydiv`, you can do this:

```
$('#mydiv a').addClass('myclass');
```

Your code:-

```
$('.myclass','a').attr('class','myclass');
```

didn't worked since, you're actually trying to find the `myclass` inside a anchor tag. So, the above code actually means:-

```
$('a').find('.myclass').attr('class','myclass');
```

or ( in case, you have typo )

```
$('a').find('#mydiv').attr('class','myclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addClass()` `.attr()`

Try this

```
$('.myclass a').addClass('myclass')  //Selector is class
$('.myclass a').attr('class','myclass');
```

In your page

```
$('#mydiv a').addClass('myclass'); //Selector is id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$('#mydiv  a').attr('class','myclass');
```

Or:

```
$('#mydiv  a').addClass('myclass');
```